# Javascript Error: n is null in swfobject.js

Tags: javascript, swfobject, microsoft-ajax

My Web application renders me "**n is null**" Javascript  error  in firefox browser when i try to access a particular page. This error originates in swfobject.js file.

Also i get another Javascript error "**a is null**" in firefox browser when i try to access a particular page.This error originates in MicrosoftAjax.js file.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that in order to get an answer your going to need to link to a page that exhibits this behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem may be that the code is trying to access an HTML element that has not loaded yet. 
To resolve this try wrap the code that is getting the errors in a jquery `ready` block if you are using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
//Code that uses SWF/MicrosoftAjax here
});
```

or if you are not using jQuery:

```
window.onload=function() // fixed windows to window
{
  //Code that uses SWF/MicrosoftAjax here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to pinpoint the problem.

99%, the problem's origin is not `swfobject.js` but in some script that's loaded before it.